# log4j.xml not writing output to a file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I wrote the below code inorder to output logger in the console as well as to a file. I am able to view the logger statements in the COnsole but not in the myStruts1App.log file I specified. Can you please let me know what is wrong in my below code. Thanks in advance

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="file" value="C:/logs/myStruts1App.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I am using the below dependency in my pom.xml

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please mention 1 more appender-ref in . As shown below.

```
<root>
     <level value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="console" />
     <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
```

TRY THIS OUT

Comment: Ok. Haapy for you :)